# Restore database in workbench from a Linux file

Tags: mysql, restore, mysql-5.6, mysql-workbench

We have a database on a Linux server. Instead of restoring using command line, can I restore it from Workbench? My backup file is in a Linux data directory.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - Yes, you can restore from MySQL Workbench.

**Explanation:**

Both MySQL Workbench and command line are clients. I hope you know about the [MySQL client-server architecture](http://www.rathishkumar.in/2016/04/understanding-mysql-architecture.html). MySQL Workbench is **GUI(Graphical User Interface)** client and **Command line(MySQL client) is a CLI(Command Line Interface) client tool.**

When you have a backup file on the Linux machine data directory, it is very easy to restore using a command line. The syntax for CLI restoration is:

```
mysql -u root -p dbname < dbbackup.sql
```

If you prefer to use MySQL workbench. Create a new connection on the MySQL dashboard by giving `hostname (Linux server hostname), MySQL username and password.` After created new connection, you will see `Import/Restore data` on the right-hand side of the window. Click on that option and it will provide you an interface to choose `database name and backup file with complete path.`

My personal choice would be command line interface. I hope this will help you!!!.

Comment: one more, if follow the question - author still have dump on Linux, so first - he need download it locally or map linux folder as local drive. WorkBench no understand remote files location